# gtag.js error Invalid or missing account ID,

Tags: gtag.js

This is how I placed my gtag and gtag.js gtag is showing green in tag assistence legecy extension
but gtag.js showing this error 'Invalid or missing account ID' I check my id again and again nothing wrong in that what I'm missing

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>

  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

  <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

I am expecting to have no error,